# Common Code Snippet Location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I have multiple VS's installed (2012, 2013, 2015). I create custom snippets but they remain in specified version's locations like `%USERPROFILE%\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets`.

Is it possible that I create a common location and all versions pick snippets from there. In that case it will be easy to maintain (add/update/remove) them and any change will affect all the versions.

Is it Possible?

Comment: have you tried Code Snippets Manager ?

Comment: @tharif: See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too eager to hit press `"Ask Question"` button.

Here are the steps:
Create a common folder and in it hierarchy like this

```
> FooBar
  > C#
  > VB.Net
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

Now, in VS go to `Tools` > `Code Snippet Manager` and select `Language` from drop down and click on `Add...` and select corresponding language folder from above hierarchy. Same for other languages and you are done.

This is a one time exercise and you are set.